# Change the answered section back to a coloured block

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is StackOverflow naked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83600/why-is-stackoverflow-naked)

The recent change to the number of answers section on the question list is far less visible at a glance than its replacement.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83600/why-is-stackoverflow-naked

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes, change it back.

Especially on a favored tag, the unanswered block is indistinguishable from an answered block.

Yes, the old version may have been ugly, but it was usable. I'm sorry, but I'll chose usability above beauty every time.

Comment: Maintaining an identical answer to two questions tends to indicate that it's a duplicate question, you should be flagging this as a duplicate instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think is should be like this:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17927147/StackOverflow/Screen%20shot%202011-03-17%20at%2019.50.42.png

That way we get rid of the yellow background (on the vote column) but can still CLEARLY see what questions are unanswered.