# Does anyone else not like the new CSS styling for the "0 Answers"?

Tags: discussion, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Eeeek! Why is StackOverflow naked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83600/eeeek-why-is-stackoverflow-naked)

**UPDATE**

Didn't notice the [Eeeek! Why is StackOverflow naked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83600/eeeek-why-is-stackoverflow-naked) post. That's *so much more* informative and alive!

#### StackOverflow, bring back the old colors! Please! Now!

---

On StackOverflow, Previously, the "0 Answers" was white text on a maroon background. Now it's maroon text on white background.

Is it just me or does anyone else find the new scheme a eye strain?

[image]

Comment: There are others who also lack an appreciation of bare, jaundiced skin. See: [Eeeek! Why is StackOverflow naked?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83600/eeeek-why-is-stackoverflow-naked)

Comment: Here's your solution: http://stackapps.com/questions/2222/gm-script-revert-changes-to-unanswered-questions-box

Answer (score 1):

I personally love it. I didn't care for the older blocky styling.

Comment: I like that "blocky" styling for the 0 answers because it makes it stand out. Accepted Answer - green background; No Accepted Answer "no" background; and No Answers - maroon background. Make so much sense!