# Can we get an enhanced style for Super User and Server Fault?

Tags: feature-request, superuser, serverfault

Ever since the new Area51 sites have been leaving beta and getting new styles, Super User and Server Fault have been patiently sitting with their current theme... which is fine, but they do look a little plain when compared to some of the other StackExchange sites.

Yes, [Jin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147574/jin) has done an **amazing** job on the StackExchange sites, and I'd love to see him add some style to SU/SF.

Therefore, I humbly request that next time there is some down time, perhaps SF/SU can get some attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree (in part), but I'd much prefer them to stay roughly as they are...

They are "The Trilogy" of original core sites that were pretty much for tech people. Their design reflects this.

I see most of these new designs (for Area 51 sites) as appropriate to capture the wider audience who would likely think SO/SU/SF are boring and simple. Jin's work is incredible but I'd argue that little should be done to change how SU/SO/SF appear because most tech people really don't care about the look...the look really has nothing to do with what StackExchange is about...(getting answers to your questions/answering peoples questions)

StackOverflow must have just recently gone through a minor design change (or colour change) and I quite like the new look (maybe just because it is new?)...but it is essentially the same look tweaked...I'm all for this similar change for SU and SF...

Comment: I agree (in part) too. I'm not advocating a **major** change - but I think in order to appear a part of the SE network of sites, there needs to be at least *some minor changes.*

Comment: I see your point, but it is these 3 sites that led to the creation of Stack Exchange...I think that says something...

Answer (score 3):

I agree and I'd also extend this request to SO itself. Stackoverflow looks a bit "boxy" right now.

Comment: Well, there seems to be [some work on that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83600/eeeek-why-is-stackoverflow-naked) already.