# Why Question is shown as Accepted Answer but actually not?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the colors on Stack Overflow mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean)

Team,

Recently, I have noticed that on Stackoverflow Questions are shown as Accepted answer on the display list but actually they are answers not accepted answer.

Refer this screenshot:-

### Picture 1: StackOverFlow - shown as accepted answer

[image]

### Picture 2: StackOverFlow - There are no accepted answer for this question

[image]

For example when I compare with Superuser Questions, I can see that questions are perfectly shown as accepted answers on the display and on the question too.

Refer this screenshot:-

### Picture 3: SuperUser - shown as accepted answer

[image]

### Picture 4: SuperUser - On the question also, it shows as accepted answer

[image]

Finally, my question is whether this is a **bug** OR **known issue** OR **not bug at all**.

### UPDATE:

On **SUPERUSER**, list makes better understandability the way it looks.

Refer the screenshot:-

[image]

### I want to recommend this type of display look on the StackOverFlow questions too.

It helps users on the first look or appearance it self.

Comment: You need to work on your highlighting.  Your red boxes are obviously drawn with the rectangle tool, not the pencil.  We expect more effort.  Freehand drawing, with red text drawn by hand, that's the ticket. :-)

Comment: If you change your support question into a feature request, please update the tags too, and remove the part where you ask whether it's a bug or not. (Or open a new question with your feature request.)

Comment: @Mat: Perfect. I think, I should raise a new question for a feature request. What you suggest?

Comment: Every site has different themes and different colors. They're not the same across every site. For example, [Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) has black text for no answers, blue text for no accepted answer, and the green background for an accepted answer. You just have to get used to each site and how its colors work.

Comment: This sounds like it could be a fairly reasonable feature request.  I'd suggest making comparisons among the three core Stack Exchange sites and various other popular ones (http://stackexchange.com/sites) and seeing if there's a pattern to which we should adhere.  The answers below highlight the distinct difference between how SU and SO handle it (no highlight -> text highlight -> box vs. no highlight -> box -> text highlight), and there's nothing wrong with suggesting consistency across the sites (just with different colors).

Comment: [This cheese was moved before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83600/eeeek-why-is-stack-overflow-naked) and there was much gnashing of teeth.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Notice that, the box you are looking at has 3 states.

1. **no** answers
2. some answers but **none are accepted**
3. contains an **accepted answer**

[image]
<sub>This screenshot is also suited for "Senior Developers" [(only called "senior" because they keep forgetting stuff)](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/users/52087/dmcs)</sub>

On the various Stack Exchange sites there might be some difference in the colour schemes; But the idea will stay the same.

As seen on [SU](https://superuser.com/),  the differences can be quite substantial - but there is still a definitive difference between questions with and without **accepted** answers.

[image]

Comment: Nice, but your GIMP seems to be stuck on the LARGE TYPE setting for older readers.

Comment: I like to place enough **emphasis** on my **emphasizing free-hand red circles** :P

Comment: @tv, how did you know I was using GIMP?  Educated guess? ;)

Comment: What self-respecting software developer would confess to using an Adobe product, even if they did? :-)

Comment: Confession - I used the Adobe uninstaller the other day :/

Comment: Thanks Lix for nice comparision.

Comment: When I see on overall, in **superuser** what it is showing most understandable.

Comment: @Siva - you are very welcome!  Why not confirm my answer by making your question have a yellow answer count ;)

Answer (score 6):

On Stack Overflow, a question with an accepted answer has the text with the number of answers in yellow. The box with the number of answers is gray only if there are no answers at all.

No answser:

[image]

Three answers, none accepted:

[image]

One answer, accepted:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mat for nice comparision.

Comment: When I see on overall, in **superuser** what it is showing most understandable.