# background behind score of question on summary tab inconsistent

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, user-interface

When I open up my profile and see the "summary" questions at the bottom, the only questions with green backgrounds are those with accepted answers.  However, in all other views on the site, green backgrounds represent *any* answers.  [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean) clarifies that the second usage is the intended.  Why is the summary tab inconsistent?
I see that in the summary it's the votes that's colored, and on the questions tab it's the number of answers, but it still seems inconsistent to me.

[image: Summary Tab]

[image: Question Tab]

In one, the green background signifies the existence of any answers, in the other, the green background signifies the existence of an accepted answer. Setting aside which is better, these should be consistent with each other.  Bart helpfully provided this mockup of a more consistent UI, where the summary tab has the same coloring as the questions tab.

[image]

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140171/can-the-status-of-whether-an-answer-has-been-accepted-be-a-separate-icon-rather

Comment: How do you expect it should be ? Please clarify.

Comment: @mtk: In one, the green background signifies the existence of _any_ answers, in the other, the green background signifies the existence of an _accepted_ answer.  Setting aside which is better, these should be consistent with each other.

Comment: @MooingDuck I think [this would be a reasonable mockup of what you expect](http://i.imgur.com/ub7iC.jpg), right? (Or at least closer to consistency)

Comment: I believe so, yes @Bart.

Comment: @Bart, I prefer the other way around. The green background if there are any answers. With such a small font, I have to squint to see the difference between the white and the yellow. And I'm fortunate enough to not be color-blind.

Comment: @Mysticial Oh, sure. The problem is mostly that 2 columns of data of one view have to be condensed into a single column in the other view. And it seems inconsistent at the moment indeed. I just attempted to clarify the point.

Comment: @Bart: Yeah, that's good.  Edited it into the question.

Comment: This seems even more confusing...the displays *should* look different, they're displaying different things. The profile one is counting *votes*, the questions page one is displaying *answers*. Make too strong a connection between the two and suddenly it seems like you're showing number of answers in the profile one.

Comment: @BenBrocka: Thats true, and something I didn't piece togeather until Bart made a demo.  Maybe the correct answer is to make them more different rather than more similar: make the background... Brown?  Or something?

Comment: @Mysticial Green is **the colour of the "accept" checkmark** and *nothing else on the site* (except these backgrounds), so green *should* be used to indicate that there is an accepted answer (in all views).  There are plenty of other ways to highlight answers in general.

Comment: @A.M. I don't remember exactly what I intended to say so long ago. But I was mainly criticizing yellow/green = accept, white/green = no accept because I have to squint to see the yellow or white in the font. It isn't a problem on the homepage since the fonts are big. But it is hard to see the difference on the example posted here.

Comment: @Mysticial ...makes sense.  I do think differences in background colour are easier to determine than differences in text colour, so it makes sense for questions with no answers and questions with answers but no accepted answers to have different backgrounds.  I am just saying that *green* is the one colour we shouldn't use for that purpose.  Following that background changes are easier to see, it seems we should be using ***three* background colours**.  For when no answers:  **white**.  For when accepted answer:  **green**.  For when at least one answer but none accepted: **any other colour**