# Profile page does not indicate if question was answered by someone else

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [View my answers to questions with no accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108225/view-my-answers-to-questions-with-no-accepted-answer)

Sometimes I want to see questions for which I posted answer, but that don't have an accepted answer. Then I can try to  improve my answer.

When I look at my profile page, though, answers are only highlighted in green if *my* answer was accepted; it doesn't indicate whether *any* answer was accepted. Should there be some indication of that? Maybe a green border could indicate an answer was accepted, but it wasn't mine.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143534/background-behind-score-of-question-on-summary-tab-inconsistent

Comment: @Mysticial Yes, that's a very closely related point in that question. Indicators are inconsistent. Maybe that should be addressed before adding new types of indicators.

Comment: Related, maybe duplicate? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108225/167443

Comment: @Jim Yes, it looks like a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

In the meantime , while the community decides what it's opinions are regarding your feature request, here is a solution to allow you to see the information you are looking for -

All you have to do is execute a search with these parameters -

```
user:1415038 is:answer isaccepted:0
```

At the time of writing this, [you have 61 posts matching these criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1415038+is%3Aanswer+isaccepted%3A0)...

The search bar has some really useful keywords that can help you get **exactly** what you want... You can [execute an empty search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=) to get to the search help page and there you will find all the keywords that are available to us.

Lets break it down -

- `user:1415038` - this will make sure that only posts that have your user id somewhere in them will be returned.
- `is:answer` - this will return only posts that are answers.
- `isaccepted:0` - this will return only answers that have not been accepted.

You'll be able to track down these posts in order to improve them.  Going through your old posts to try and improve them is a great idea!

<sub>One may argue that with this functionality, your feature request is rendered obsolete :)</sub>

Comment: Hey, thanks. I just tried the search, but it doesn't filter out questions that have been answered but not by me.